# How to host the website in svn local host to IIS server

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a svn repository in my machine.The website are hosted locally in my machine.I access it through the localhost address.How to host the website from svn server to a IIS server.I use Tortoise SVN.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot publish the SVN Repositories via IIS. You can use Apache, svn server, or SSH. These are all free. However there is a paid option `SVNIsapi`.